# ActiveRecord has_many association doesn't call after_destroy when setting a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

3 models: User, Movie, Like

```
User has_many :likes
User has_many :movies, through: :likes
```

This code:

```
user.movies = [ m1, m2, m3 ]
```

calls `Like#after_create` for the new `Like` records that relate user and m1/m2/m3. Then, this code:

```
user.movies = [ m3, m4 ]
```

doesn't call `Like#after_destroy` for the `Like` records that relate user to m1/m2, but does call `Like#after_create` for the new relationship with m4.

The `movies` collection could be set manually or with a form that has `user[movie_ids]` checkboxes, and then

```
user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

1. What is the right Rails approach for setting a collection?
2. How do I force it to call after_destroy?

## Update:

As @jdoe cited from the docs, it's not achievable when assigning new collection or when deleting from a collection (`user.movies.delete(m1)`). The only way is to use `before_remove`/`after_remove` callbacks on the user model (and in case of a polymorphic relationship -- any other model), with the `has_many` definition:

```
has_many :movies, through: :likes, before_remove: :before_like_destroy, after_remove: after_like_destroy

def before_like_destroy(movie)
  like = self.likes.where(movie_id: movie)
  # trigger the after_destroy on like
  like.trigger_before_destroy # to be implemented on like, should call what the original callbacks contained
end

def after_like_destroy(movie)
  # no way to get Like object here because it was already removed, need to remember it on the before_destroy somehow
end
```

Can't understand the logic behind it. It makes callbacks on relationship models totally useless. If something happened on `after_create` it can't be undone in `after_destroy`, and since it's better practice to have after and before logic together and not separately, it makes all callbacks useless.

Think I'm gonna write a gem that does that automagically.

Comment: Where's that gem?  11 years later and this behaviour is bonkers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to docs:

> collection=objects
>
> Replaces the collections content by deleting and adding objects as
>   appropriate. If the :through option is true callbacks in the join
>   models are triggered **except destroy callbacks**, since deletion is
>   direct.

Comment: What gets destroyed is the `Like` records (the relationship table w/ user_id and movie_id). And I do expect the after_destroy to fire on those like records.
I edited the question to emphasize that I expect the callbacks on the `Like` records.

Comment: That's right, but WHY is it like that? What's the logic? I have to have this after_destroy. Is the only way to monkey patch?

Comment: @elado I would recommend you to use the `:after_remove` callback of `User has_many` association. See the section *4.5 Association Callback* here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks. It will be triggered on `@user.movies = [...]`.

Comment: `before`/`after_remove` has to be on all other side relationships... Really weird decision by the rails guys. That means that `after_destroy` is essentially useless on relationship models.

Thanks. Marking this as an answer, because there's no other way.

Comment: @elado I don't know why you say it is weird, but I like this distinction: generic callbacks, like `before_create`, access the record being processed. But `after_remove` gets **associated** record (or both if you pass Proc). This way your joined table is transparently eliminated from being mentioned in your code. It looks like you are really removing your movies form the user :)

Comment: The reason for asking it, is that I've created this gem, neoid, https://github.com/elado/neoid that mirrors DB records into nodes and relationships in Neo4j graph DB. I injected after_create and after_destroy into every Node and Relationship records, but when something is being edited with a form (that uses the common way of `user.update_attributes(params[:user])` and this hash contains :movie_ids array) -- it doesn't trigger the after_destroy of the relationship, so my code won't update the graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you add dependent: :destroy to both the like and movie associations, it calls the after_destroy callback